Can you produce Non-Clifford gates via Lattice Surgery?
Is there any theorem stating that lattice merge/split operations (or perhaps more generally, so-called gauge-fixing) cannot produce a non-Clifford gate that can complete the universal gateset for the surface code?

Merge and split can be performed with stabilizer operations (up to feedback due to ZX defining merge to use postselection whereas real computers have measurement instead):

Therefore if merge or split could do non-Clifford gates, you could do non-stabilizer gates with stabilizer gates.
You can't do non-Clifford (more generally: non-stabilizer) gates with only stabilizer gates and states. That's why they are called non-Clifford gates.
Therefore you can't do non-Clifford gates with merge and split operations.
